# Integer within range

Tags: php

Trying to do something that will ask for the income, then check to see if the income is within the acceptable range of say 0 - 100,000, and if not spit out the error msg

```
<form name="frm1" action="#" method="post">
   Income:<br>
   <input type="number" name="income_val" /><br>
   <input type="submit" name="submitbtn" value="Submit Form" />
</form>
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
    $error_msg= array();
    $val=(int)$_POST['income_val'];
    if(){
        $error_msg[] = "Must be between 0 and 100000";
    }
    if(isset($error_msg) && count($error_msg) == 0){

       echo "Your Income is ".$_POST['income_val']."<br>";
    }
    else{
       foreach ($error_msg as $result) {
         echo $result;
       }
    }
}
```

Line 10, where the if() is, is where I'm trying to set it up. The code runs, just can't seem to get it to actually spit out the error when the value isn't within the range with what I was trying.

Comment: Does the form submit? Do you get errors? Have you tried using `<` and `>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $error_msg = array();
    if (isset($_POST['income_val'])) { 
        $val = (int) $_POST['income_val'];
    } else {
        $error_msg[] = "There is no value!";
    }
    if (isset($val) && ($val > 100000 || $val < 0)) {
        $error_msg[] = "Must be between 0 and 100000";
    }

    if (isset($error_msg) && count($error_msg) == 0) {
       echo "Your Income is " . $_POST['income_val'] . "<br>";
    } else {
       foreach ($error_msg as $result) {
         echo $result;
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Edited to account for that, though my condition was just intended as a starting point :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
<form name="frm1" action="#" method="post">
   Income:<br>
   <input type="number" name="income_val" /><br>
   <input type="submit" name="submitbtn" value="Submit Form" />
</form>

<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
    $error_msg = array();
    $val = (int)$_POST['income_val'];
    $min = 0;
    $max = 100000;
    if($val >= $max || $val <= $min){
        $error_msg[] = "Must be between ".$min." and ".$max;
    }
    if(isset($error_msg) && count($error_msg) == 0){

       echo "Your Income is ".$_POST['income_val']."<br>";
    }
    else{
       foreach ($error_msg as $result) {
         echo $result;
       }
    }
}
?>
```